# A function searching through an array of structures (C)

Tags: c, arrays, search

This is an address:

```
struct Adress {
    char name[31], lastname[31], email[48];
};
```

The goal is to have an address book in the main function, and the user should be able to type in a string, and the program lists out all of the people from the address book whose name or the last name contains the given string.
For example, if the address book contains "john" "doe", "jane" "doey" and "george" "johnson", and the user types in "doe", the output is:

```
 1. john doe johndoe@email.com
 2. jane doey janedoey@email.com
```

This part of the main function should use a function

```
int search(struct Adress array[], int size_of_the_addressbook, char* string_to_search)
```

which returns the index of the first found address, and -1 in case no address has been found.

Here's my try:

In the snippet from my main function (there 's no need to post input stuff here):

```
    struct Adress adressbook[1000], *member;
    int i = 0;
    member = adressbook;

    if (search(member, number_of_elements, string_to_seach)) == -1)
                printf("No person found.\n");

    else while((search(member, number_of_elements, string_to_seach)) != -1)
            {
                member = adressbook + search(member, number_of_elements, string_to_seach);
                ++i;


                printf("%d. %s %s - %s\n", i, (*member).name, (*member).lastname, (*member).email);
                ++member;
            }
```

And here's the search function:

```
int search(struct Adress array[], int size_of_the_addressbook, char* string_to_search)
{
    int j, index;
    struct Adress *i;
    i = array;

    while (strstr((*i).name, string_to_search) == 0 && strstr((*i).lastname, string_to_search) == 0)
    {
        index = ((i - array)/(sizeof (struct Adress)));
        if (index == size_of_the_addressbook)   return -1;
        ++i;
    }
    index = ((i - array)/(sizeof (struct Adresa)));
    return index;
}
```

However, this program gets stuck in an infinite loop in pretty much any case when there is more than one member in the address book. I'm suspecting that in the while loop the search doesn't go on from the previously found member, but rather it starts from the begin each time, therefore it keeps finding the same, firstly found member each time.

Comment: Why invoke search *twice* ?? Once, saving the result, testing for -1, and if not, use the result as an offset rather than invoking the same function with the same parameters *again* ? And you don't need the division calculation of `index` in `search`. Pointer math will do that for you. `index = (i - array);` should be sufficient to get the correct index.

Comment: Hm, how would I get the index without this division?
And I know things could be optimised a bit, but primarily I need to make it work and figure out why does it get into an infinite loope.

Comment: This is strangely written code. Why not just use an integer index `i` which iterates from `0` to the length of the array and reference, `array[i].name`, etc? As far as the infinite loop, how is `size_of_the_addressbook` computed before being passed to the function?

Comment: Again, *pointer arithmetic*. Its done twice in this code, both wrong. No sizeof division is needed for what you're doing.

Comment: Lurker, I need to make a function like this because it's what my homework makes me.
And when it comes to the case when no strings are found, you're right about, I actually have a part of the code that deals with it but I forgot to copy it. I'll add it now.

Comment: Does your homework assignment specifically state that you have to iterate through the array with a pointer rather than an index? You still haven't shown how `number_of_elements` is computed.

Comment: lurker: number_of_elements starts from zero and gets incremented when the address book gets a new element.
In the homework assigment, I am given what I wrote in the question (its parameters, and what should be returned).

Comment: Right. So your loop inside the function can still iterate `int i` from `0` to `number_of_elements-1` referencing `array[i]`. It would be much cleaner, and your loop would at least properly terminate, leaving you to address other issues.

Comment: But how can I figure out the beginning index? It's not necessarily 0.
edit: nevermind

Comment: lurker so if I start with i from 0 to size-1, perhaps the argument points to the 5th member of the array, I'll have to many iterations . So I need first to figure out the index of the passed member? And it'll eventually end up the same.

Comment: In the comment to the answer below I described the problem, perhaps that might help you locating the error:

Say that I have two members with the same last name and different first names. If I search for the last name (or a part of it) the program prints out infinite lines of i. first member's name first member's last name, with i going from 1 to infinity.

Comment: @BaneBojanić have you examined the answer I posted?

Comment: @Lurker, yes, but your fix doesn't quite work for my original program... I translated the program's variables into English to make it readable, here, you can try compiling it yourself: http://pastebin.com/AbzjXAGw

Comment: Your original question was about trying to figure out why your function was getting into an infinite loop, which I believe I determined the cause of. If you're question is now about "how do I get my whole program to work?", then that's increased scope. The problem now appears to be outside of the function in question.

Comment: Of course. I'm not asking people to revise the whole program (the rest works okay, actually), just this function + its context in the main function (case 4 in the switch).

Comment: I just gave you the whole program in case you wanted to see for yourself what happens when the function is ran.

Answer (score 1):

You have a few problems to mention

1. You call `search()` twice in your main loop which is absolutely unnecessary, you should call it once and store it's return value.
2. Your `member` pointer, never points after the first match, so the first match will always be found, 
   leading to an infinite loop.
3. You increase the `member` pointer and still pass `number_of_elements` to the search function. When you increase the `member` pointer the number of elements left to the right of it's resulting position is decreased by the same number that you increase `member`.
4. This expression is not giving the value you think

   ```
   ((i - array)/(sizeof (struct Adress)));
   ```

   because you are computing the distaince between the two pointers `i` and `array` and then dividing it by `sizeof(struct Address)` which is `110`, and as another answer mentioned, the value is automatically scaled, so

   ```
   ((i - array)/(sizeof (struct Adress))); -> i - array;
   ```

   to see what I mean you may try to print this values

   ```
   printf("\t%d\n", ((void*)member - (void*)adressbook));
   printf("\t%d\n", ((void*)member - (void*)adressbook) / sizeof(*member));
   printf("\t%d\n", member - adressbook);
   ```

   **Note**: if your OS is 64bit, change the format specifier to `"%ld"`.

This is the code that will do what you need

```
int search(struct Adress **array, int size_of_the_addressbook, char* string_to_search)
{
    int            index;
    struct Adress *pointer;

    if ((size_of_the_addressbook == 0) || (array == NULL) || (*array == NULL))
        return -1;

    pointer = *array;
    index   = 0;
    while (strstr(pointer->name, string_to_search) == 0 && 
               strstr(pointer->lastname, string_to_search) == 0)
    {
        /* check that we are not at the end of the array. */
        if (++index == size_of_the_addressbook)
            return -1;
        /* not found yet, increment both arrays */
        (*array)++;

        pointer = *array;
    }

    return index;
}
```

and in `main()`

```
int index;
int foundIndex;

index = 1;
while ((foundIndex = search(&member, number_of_elements, string_to_seach)) != -1)
{
    printf("%d. %s %s - %s\n", index, member->name, member->lastname, member->email);

    index              += 1 + foundIndex;
    number_of_elements -= 1 + foundIndex;

    ++member;
}
```

in this approach, the `member` pointer is increased inside the `search()` function to point to the found element, a counter is added to reflect how much was advanced.

After the `search()` function returns, member should be increased by 1 again to point to the next element, and `number_of_elements` should be decreased by the number of elements advanced in the search function + 1 for the found element.

Also, keep a variable that you update on each iteration that gives you the actual `index` of the element in the array.

Comment: If i compare it with size_of_the_addressbook -1, it still gets stuck inside an infinite loop.

Comment: @BaneBojanić How can you tell that it's an infinite loop? did you use a debugger?

Comment: Say that I have two members with the same last name and different first names. If I search for the last name (or a part of it) the program prints out infinite lines of i. first member's name first member's last name, with i going from 1 to infinity.

Comment: @BaneBojanić why are you calling search twice?

Comment: trouble? what trouble?, I was having a lot of fun with your code... :) I hope it hepls you.

Answer (score 1):

Your search never actually returns -1, and your invoke of that search doesn't thusly have an exit condition.  Further, you should be adjust each *starting point* of the next search to be one slot *beyond* the last discovery point.

I'm nearly certain this is what you're *trying* to do. I've not tested this (have no data to do so nor any info on the invocation of this functionality), but I hope the point is obvious:

```
int search(const struct Adress array[],
           int size_of_the_addressbook,
           const char* string_to_search)
{
    const struct Adress *end = array + size_of_the_addressbook;
    const struct Adress *i = array;

    for (; i != end; ++i)
    {
        if (strstr(i->name, string_to_search) != NULL ||
            strstr(i->lastname, string_to_search) != NULL)
            break;
    }

    return i == end ? -1 : (int)(i - array);
}

void do_search(const struct Adress *array,
               int number_of_elements,
               const char *string_to_search)
{
    int i = search(array, number_of_elements, string_to_search), base=0;
    if (i == -1)
    {
        printf("No person found.\n");
        return;
    }

    while (i != -1)
    {
        base += i;
        printf("%d. %s %s - %s\n", base,
               array[base].name,
               array[base].lastname,
               array[base].email);

        base += 1;

        // note adjustment of starting point using pointer arithmetic.
        i = search(array + base,
                   number_of_elements - base,
                   string_to_search);
    }
}
```

Hope it helps. Best of luck.

Comment: This line:
*end = array + size_of_the_addressbook;

array + size_of_the addressbook might go beyond the addressbook array?

edit: nevermind, I saw the adjustment in the second function.

Comment: Unfortunately, your function prints out an infinite number of lines containing the firstly found member, exactly like my function did...

Comment: @BaneBojanić yeah, I just realized that. `base` was not being adjusted correctly. It should work now. That'll teach me to post untested code.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I guess I should've posted the whole code, but it was difficult because I'd have to translate all the variables to English to make it readable...